# Can the class itself see transcluded content?

Tags: typescript, angular, transclusion

So in Angular2, the following is pretty simple:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some',
  properties: ['header']
})
@View({
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{ getFormattedHeader() }}</h2>
      <p><content></content></p>
    </div>
  `
})
class SomeComponent {
  header: string;

  getFormattedHeader() {
    return this.header + '!';
  }
}
```

```
<some header="Header Text">Content</some>
```

And you get this:

```
<div>
  <h2>Header Text!</h2>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

But what if I wanted to apply formatting on the content? Can I write a `getFormattedContent()` function, and if so what do I replace `this.header` with?

For that matter, I could have chosen to use `format(header)` in the template, with a `format` method that took a string and returned that string with a `!`. Is there anything I could put in the template that would be akin to `format(` `<content></content>` `)`? Obviously my `format` method would need to be a little more complicated since `<content></content>` is not a string, but that’s not a particularly significant problem so long as I know its type (`ElementCollection`? `NodeList`?).

Obviously, there is a workaround by just shoving everything in attributes and leaving the content empty, but I find that ugly (particularly since one cannot apparently define tags that require no close).

Comment: if its like in angular 1, the transcluded content cannot 'see' inside the class, it only sees the same 'scope' as in the template where the '<some>' element is

Comment: @jhadesdev Thanks for taking the time to try to help! Unfortunately, 1. I’m not *very* familiar with Angular.js, but Angular2 is supposed to have completely reworked scope, so Angular 1 stuff probably won’t help, and 2. If I’ve understood you correctly, I actually mean the opposite of that: I want the inside of the class to 'see' the content; I don’t want the content to 'see' the inside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Valid for **Angular 2.0.0-alpha.45**

If you are interested in child elements, that are directives or variable bindings, then this will work:

import {Component, Query QueryList} from 'angular2/angular2';

```
@Component({
    selector: 'c-item',
    template: '<li><ng-content></ng-content></li>'
})
export class CItem {
}


@Component({
    selector: 'c-container',
    template: '<div><ul><ng-content></ng-content></ul><strong>{{children.length}} items found.</strong></div>',
    directives: [CItem]
})
export class CContainer {
    private children:QueryList<CItem>;

    constructor(@Query(CItem) children:QueryList<CItem>) {
            this.children = children;
    }

    afterContentInit() {
            // now this.children variable is initialized properly
    }
}
```

Comment: I sadly am unlikely to have an opportunity to test this code in the very-near future (maybe this weekend? but if not it may be several weeks), but thank you very much for giving me something to work with when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

Valid for **Angular 2.0.0-alpha.45**

You can consider a *directive* that allows you to access a HTMLElement and its children as well.
Consider an example:

```
import {Directive, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ElementRef, HTMLElement} from 'angular2/angular2';


@Directive({
    selector: '[my-border]',
    inputs: [
    'definition : my-border' // attribute my-border to var definition
    ]
})
export class MyBorder {
    private definition:string;
    private elementRef : ElementRef;

    constructor(elementRef : ElementRef) {
        this.elementRef = elementRef;
    }

    afterContentInit() {
        // now this.children variable is initialized properly
        let htmlEl:HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        htmlEl.setAttribute('style', 'border:' + this.definition);
    }
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
<span my-border="dashed #00b3ee thin;">This has directive my-border</span>
```

The *htmlEl* in *afterContentInit* refers to *span* DOM element.
As a result you get:

```
<span my-border="dashed #00b3ee thin;" style="border:dashed #00b3ee thin;">This has directive my-border</span>
```

Comment: Does this give you access to the element content? Could you, for instance, perform string manipulation on it?

Comment: This is native DOM element so you can do everything what pure JavaScript allows.